# Communication betwen sharepoint apps on different pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, query-string

I'm developing two client web parts on the same sharepoint hosted app project.
Client web part A shows a list of employees of the month(name, picture, etc)
Client web part B shows the detailed information for a certain employee of the month

What i'm trying to achieve is to redirect the user form the page that holds the CWP A to the page that contains CWP B when clicking an element from A.

I've tried without success by using query string. I've read that you could communicate two apps with post message, but as i see it, that scenario won't apply to mine..

What could i do?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 6/9/2015**

Redirect means clicking on  element and open the client web part b on different page, but same tab. In order to achieve this client web part A has a property named redirect Url which represents the url where client web part B is located, my initial idea was to append a query string to that url. 
However when i redirect to the page with the query string ?Id=2 (for example),
the page won't load any client webpart, leaving a blank page.

Comment: Why won't postMessage work? It should easily be able to handle what you need.

Comment: Because the client web parts are on different pages..and all the examples i found talked about having both CWP on the same page. I'd rather use post message than my current solution but perhaps there is something i'm missing.

Comment: So, you have PageA with WebPartA, PageB with WebPartB.  You want a link in WebPartA to open PageB, and pass info to WebPartB? If so, simply have your link include a querystring option to PageB, and then use postMessage to pass that to the webpart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fellows, finally i got the solution. I found this [page](https://prasantabarik.wordpress.com/2013/09/26/pass-querystring-value-from-sharepoint-page-to-app-partclient-web-part/) that explains how to pass value from a sharepoint page to a client webpart.

Basically what i had to do in order to retrieve the page query string and send it to the iFrame was the following:

1 - Add a property to the client web part (should have the same name as the query string that will be passed).

2 - Add a script editor/content editor below the client web part with a script that would retrieve the value from the query string, validate a couple of things and then replace the value of the property defined the client web part

For a detailed information check the link below!

Thanks @eirikb and @kesava for the help! I really appreciate it

Comment: You should edit your answer to include the main part of the link in it.  Link-only answers become useless should the link break, or the content change.

Answer (score 1):

To me it sounds like you want a normal link (`a`-tag) to the other app.
One way to achieve this is by getting the app tile **from host web** and create a link to the tile target, something like this:

```
_api/Web/AppTiles?$filter=Title eq 'Your app title'&$select=Target
```

(note you need to use [AppContextSite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179927.aspx) endpoint.)

Then select the first result, and create an `a`-tag with the value as href:

```
'<a href="' + items[0].Target + '">link</a>'
```

### Update:

One way to communicate between SharePoint hosted client web parts (app parts) is to use `postMessage`, here is [an article (My SharePoint Insight)](http://mysharepointinsight.blogspot.no/2013/08/how-to-pass-parameters-between-your-app.html) by Borislav Grgić.

As far as I understand the app parts can't communicate directly, i.e., you need some code on the **parent page** where you add the app parts, something like this:

App A <-> Parent page <-> App B

#### Listening

In order to listen for messages you can use `addEventListener` function on the global `window` object:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  console.log('event', event.data);
});
```

#### Sending

When sending you call `postMessage`.
**Important**: When calling `postMessage` you need to reference the `window` object you want to send a message to.

From app part

`parent` will be parent page `window` object inside the app part iframe.

```
window.parent.postMessage({message:'Hello, world!'},'*');
```

From parent page

On the parent page you must find the iframe element(s) and use `contentWindow`.

```
document.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow.postMessage({message:'Hello, world!'},'*');
```

#### Glue

Now you need to glue this together. On the parent page you need to listen for messages from both app parts and *proxy* these messages between them. The information above should be sufficient to get you going.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, however i think this won't apply for my situation, I've edited my question, check it out and let me know your thoughts. Thanks again

Comment: i tried this with both client web parts on same page and worked like charm. However, i can't see how i could use this when having both client web parts on different pages. Keep in mind that client web part b wont load unless user clicks CWP a's item. The click will trigger the post message which should be sent o a CWP that isn't loaded, ready yet. Maybe i lack of certain knowledge and that's why i cant' see it through

Comment: If you want to have them on different pages my solution would not work, then you would have to do something like what @kesava mentions, although then you need to deploy a C#-project externally (a lot more to it than a simple SharePoint hosted app) - could also look at other options, e.g., what about opening and closing a firebase connection (hacky)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are having issues in reading the query string via java script. if thats the case then you may refer the below one for detailed answer.

[Link for query string in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647259/javascript-query-string)

if you are really looking for a connected apps architecture, then I would suggest to use "SignalR" with SharePoint. There are couple of very good articles mentioned in MSDN and SharePoint blogs in internet.

Pls go through the below links as references.

[Link-1](http://www.mavention.com/blog/building-sharepoint-apps-signalr)

[Link-2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2014/05/14/connected-sharepoint-app-parts-with-signalr.aspx)